# File upload change event in IE

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am currently experiencing great difficulty getting the change event to fire when doing a drag-n-drop interaction in internet explorer as part of a file upload operation. The code I have is very basic:

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top: 5%;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div id="uploadArea" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
            <p>Drag your files here or click in this area</p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    }

    <div id="validationArea">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ValidationMessage, new { id = "validationMessage", style = "color: red;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('form input').change(function() {
    $('form p').text(this.files.length + " file(s) selected");
    $('#uploadArea').css('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

This event fires in Chrome and Firefox just fine but **only** fires in IE if I 'click' (essentially the drag-n-drop don't work son!).

Comment: What version of IE are you using? IE10 is the first version of Internet Explorer to support file drag and drop.

Comment: Well so far I've only been testing in Edge and as far as I am aware it's supported in that. Playing around with the code a little I can handle a drop event in IE and it registers correctly but then I start getting issues with Chrome and Firefox.